# Create an excel spreadsheet that actively modifies an access database

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

My client wants to store basic relational data in Access. So far, so good. However, ideally, he'd like for me to create an Excel spreadsheet that would allow users to create and modify data types without having to work with Access software or know about databases. To be more specific, he wants a single master spreadsheet that would let people manage data for several different "projects." Each project would have basic attributes and other related data such as employees working on it, numbered to do items with associated data, etc. I've worked with databases before and it's a neat, textbook example of a relational database. I have a model for the data already, and making an Access form to fill it in would be straightforward.

However, here's the thing: he wants creating new attributes and tables completely intuitive within the Excel spreasheet--as easy as clicking an "add student" button or even add a new category of data. For instance, in the future, he may add a list of contractors working on the project, and it would be nice to be able to have a button that would allow you to essentially create that new table. There won't be a great amount of data, though, and I'm not sure if referential integrity and normalization is crucial. For instance, the list of contractors he creates wouldn't need to be perfectly linked up so that each company only appears once in the database.

So, what should I do? Can I accomplish this within Excel spreadsheets using macros? Can you make buttons in Excel that would say "create a new table," which would (run a VBScript to) create a new database table to be associated with each project, and then allow you to format it? Should I not bother with Excel at all and basically write a Visual Basic program? I'm familiar with general programming and databases, but I am fairly new to Excel, Access, and Visual Basic. If you could point me in the right direction--to tutorials, examples, advice, general concepts, etc--it would be much appreciated.

Comment: It seems like you will be creating the Access UI inside of Excel. Viewing or updating data from an existing structure in Excel makes sense if Access is scary or buying Access licenses for everyone is too expensive. If you do recreate the entire UI in Excel, it will be just as scary as the Access UI, and probably cost more than the Access licenses. Distributing Access with a customized Ribbon that hides all the things the client currently believes that they don't need (but probably will want eventually) seems like an easier and cheaper solution.

Comment: @Matt Agree with you, however it is possible to distribute the application as runtime with no need for Access licence to deploy: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb501030(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Access runtime is free, there is no license fee: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10910

Comment: "Intuitive" and "database design" (adding tables/attributes) seem at odds with each other.  I'm not sure this would be a good idea even if you could manage to build it. It might start out OK, but would likely soon evolve (devolve?) into a bit of a dog's dinner as random folk add/tweak the underlying tables.

Comment: I agree with you, Tim, but the client has hired me to do this and I'm going to do my best to meet their demands. I will try shaking them down to see if I can't get a full, comprehensive description of the database so I can set it and forget it. On the other hand, it seems like I could make some kind of program to let users add new tables within a project, since the relations won't get too complex. I could have "add new field"/"add new table" within the basic project entry form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel is essentially for analyzing data, while Access is essentially for storing and  processing relational data. Now, having said that, what you are trying to do is probably possible but it is really not taking advantage of the features the software where optimized for.

Furthermore, adding "tables to be associated with each project" does not seem as the "relational way of doing it", like a complex solution for a simple problem.

Perhaps you should consider some alternatives:

- If the amount of data is small and not very complex, would there really be any need for Access or could you just as well use Excel for data storage and data manipulation?
- Depending on how the data is structured, perhaps you can create a view or stored procedure in Access and used it as an linked table in Excel?
- Perhaps you can develop the set of forms you need in Access and turn it to an stand-alone application (no need for Access installed on the client's computers)

Comment: Right. Err, I didn't mean to have tables to be associated with each project--fear not, I'm familiar with database normalization. My project will be like your typical relational database, albeit maybe simple enough to forgo standard techniques and use Excel. Also, I'm working under the following constraints: 1. Users don't want to deal heavily with Access--or at all--beyond a very simple intuitive form. 2. Excel will be challenging due to the relational nature of the data, but perhaps I can figure something out.  3. I want to do a damn good job because I just started working at the client site.

Comment: Furthermore, could you have something along the lines of a drop down menu that says "project 1, project 2, project 3, add new project"? Is there any way at all to store one-to-many relationships in Excel, even if it's a hack? How could one project store multiple employees without a relational model?

Comment: Then what you might want to do is working with linked tables (if your data can be structured as such) or setting up some stored procedures in Access, and then send parameters through Excel VBA or invoke the SQL-queries directly from there using ADODB or DAO.

Comment: In the case of the drop-down menu I guess what you could do is to make an event to run on select and then if selected value is the value of "add new project" then invoke a procedure for that event whatever that might be. As of your second question, perhaps consolidate is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hmm, I'll look into linked tables. But my client was pointing out some spreadsheets he created, and pointed to one section that had an "employees" with multiple fields. In less technical terms, he specifically mentioned that he wanted something that could provide that one-to-many relationship, without having some kind of maximum number of employees on a single form. I asked him "will you have more of these kinds of [one-to-many] relationships?" and he said maybe. He also said that, if this is successful, it will be used as a model throughout the company.

Comment: So, I might indeed need to use Access, but dressed up nicely. Unless, of course, you believe that users can easily create new tables by specifying that they need more one-to-many relationships. I think everything will just need to relate back to "projects"--that is, I won't need to write queries joining other tables--so that will simplify things.

Comment: @slothario Use Access, perhaps with SQL Server Express. Excel is not going to scale well. Access may be challenging enough for a a model to be used throughout the company.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what they mean by "use throughout the company." I'm assuming that they'll be using it for various small projects like the one I'm specifically designing it for, but I don't know yet.

Comment: I am not sure I follow. Why would a user need to create tables in the DB to accomplish simple tasks, that to me suggest poor DB design. Technically you may do this in Excel, however as I and Matt was pointing out, it might not be the simplest, therefore best solution for you and the users.

Comment: Okay, here's a screenshot of what they currently have: http://i.imgur.com/Suepy.png. There's a spreadsheet for every single project--I think there's ten projects currently. He wants to consolidate them. My client says he may want to add fields to the spreadsheet: for instance, maybe he wants to add a "number of sponsors" field to the project, or in addition to a list of students, also a list of employees. He'd also like the number of students or employees to be unlimited. On top of all of this, it has to be easy enough for anyone to use.

Comment: "I want to do a damn good job because I just started working at the client site." Part of doing a good job is telling clients when their ideas are unworkable and not in their best interests. Designing a system like this sounds like a giant headache using the wrong tools for the job. If it's a database system, use Access. That's what it's for.

Comment: Right. Well, I've explained why we need databases. I've enumerated the different solutions and their consequences, and hopefully, this one will be acceptable for them even though they want a freely modifiable system.

Comment: OK, I can see where he is going with this. Essentially, he would like to turn a form into an application and still utilize the benefits of them both (by adding and removing fields as he likes, yet manipulating data not by adding separate spreadsheets for each project, but by retrieving them from a database). I fear this is not going to work very well. Your client have to chose one of these needs for this specific task. You could indeed make the application in Excel alone by storing the data in a non relational fashion and retrieving/updating them with some simple VBA.

Comment: If you need a model which can support extensible attributes and the ability to add different "types" then you could look a little at the "entity-attribute-value" approach, but be warned it is not as easy to implement as it might appear.

Answer (score 0):

For a person entering data, Access is built so they don't need to understand relational data at all. If you let them enter data in Excel, you will have to excessively code it to give you the same control in Access or you run the risk of letting them free form data to the point you won't be able to import it back into Access.

Unless there are very complex calculations and a need for the user to 'tweak' the report layout, give them a data entry form.

Beware of the "I'm just so use to doing it in Excel I don't want to relearn it in Access" notion. The data entry can be made very intuitive and may save them time in the long-run.

Seems like there is an owner/manager who understands Excel and wants the ability to update it without you if needed.

Comment: "Seems like there is an owner/manager who understands Excel and wants the ability to update it without you if needed." Yep, that's the point. I'm a consultant hired on for a month. I offered to train someone how to update Access, though, or write a short manual.

Comment: Not sure either. 'Twasn't me.